# Java/Spring Batch update returned unexpected row count from update

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am currently working on a project and I can't seem to find out what causes this problem, I've tried a lot of suggestions I found at other peoples problems.

This here is my Business Objective class, a Business Objective class is a part of a Workshop and a workshop of course has users

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BUSINESS_OBJECTIVE")
public class BusinessObjective implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "OBJECTIVE", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String objective;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userid")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "workshopid")
    private Workshop workshop;
```

This controller here seems to get the right values, since I printed them out in the commandline.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/bodashboard/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processBOform(
            @ModelAttribute("businessObjective") BusinessObjective businessObjective,
            @PathVariable int id,
            BindingResult result
    ) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {    
            return "participant/workshop/bodashboard";

        }

        String user = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
        Workshop workshop = workshopService.findById(id);


        BOService.addBO(businessObjective, workshop, user);

        return "participant/workshop/bodashboard";

    }
```

This here is my Service implementation

```
    public void addBO(BusinessObjective BO, Workshop workshop, String username) {

        User user = userDao.findByUsername(username);
        BO.setUser(user);
        BO.setWorkshop(workshop);

        BODAO.addBO(BO);
    }

}
```

And finally in the DAO implementation, it saves or updates the business objective:

```
public void addBO(BusinessObjective BO){
    saveOrUpdate(BO);
}
```

But when I try to to this, it keeps throwing this Batch error at me. Hope anyone can help me out with this, have been trying a while to save this model

The full error below:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.hva.klm.model.BusinessObjective

type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.hva.klm.model.BusinessObjective

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.hva.klm.model.BusinessObjective
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:168)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:120)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)

root cause

org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.hva.klm.model.BusinessObjective
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:139)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
    com.hva.klm.dao.AbstractDao.persist(AbstractDao.java:54)
    com.hva.klm.dao.implementation.BusinessObjectiveDAOImpl.save(BusinessObjectiveDAOImpl.java:27)
    com.hva.klm.service.BusinessObjectiveServiceImpl.save(BusinessObjectiveServiceImpl.java:38)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy486.save(Unknown Source)
    com.hva.klm.controller.participant.WorkshopController.processBOform(WorkshopController.java:175)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:168)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:120)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
```

Comment: Add the stacktrace

Comment: yes edited it already :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19610608/hibernate-exception-detached-entity-passed-to-persist